# How to See Errors in ajax.php

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, email

I call `ajax.php` through an AJAX request and try to parse the `JSON` when it responds.
I have a `mail()` function in `ajax.php` which causes error. I need to see what error it is.
It's really weird.. I've been struggling with it for hours.

When I access ajax.php through browser, the `mail()` works and I am able to receive the email.
But when I call via `AJAX`, and read the response, it gives `parserror` and it's not good enough to find the cause. Here's the simplified code:

`ajax.php`:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
error_log("test");

goto mail;

//skipped code

mail:
try {

    $message = 'Test Mail';
    $from = "info@example.com";
    $to = "info@example.com";
    $subject = "Application";
    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $errors[] = $e->getMessage();
}

if(count($errors)>0){
    echo json_encode(array('status'=>'error','message'=>implode($errors,'<br>')));
}
die();
```

`global.js`:

```
$('#theForm').on('submit',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    let formData = new FormData();

    formData.append('fname',$('#theForm input[name=first_name]').val());
    //... appending lots of data + file

    $.ajax({
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: '/lib/ajax.php',
        data: formData,
        success: function (data) {
            //celebrate
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
            $('.submit-result').html(textStatus);
        },
        timeout: 5000
    });
});
```

PS. I wish I could have error_log so I could see the PHP errors. It's a subdomain on a shared hosting, so I can't edit php.ini. But it does create error_log on the main domain.

Comment: What exactly is the error message except `parseerror`? Did you also check your browser inspect tool on the Network tab? Maybe also try to add `console.log(textStatus); on the error function.

Comment: Thanks! I used console.log, but it doesn't give more details; just `parseerror`. However I checked the network tab of inspect element. It's a surprise for me that it shows the PHP error as the response in the preview sub-tab. That resolves my issue. Thanks again. :)

Comment: Glad to help you! I also post this as an answer then, so future visitors can benefit from this. Would be glad if you could upvote and accept it as the correct answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the `Network` with your browser inspect tools. I especially recommend the Chrome browser by Google for that.

More insights: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network